# Problems Loading Object which needs to evalute object with DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, snapshot

I'm having an issue with fetching the object data to fill an array from Firebase to Flutter.

So I got this function:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetListings() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('listings').get();

    List<Listing> listingList = [];

    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) async {
      List<String> images = [];

      document.get('photos').forEach((photo) {
        images.add(photo);
      });

      DocumentSnapshot favoriteSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc('userfavorites/${user.uid}/favorites/${document.id}')
          .get();

      listingList.add(
        Listing(
          id: document.id,
          photos: images,
          price: double.parse(document.get('price').toString()),
          status: document.get('status'),
          street: document.get('street'),
          street2: document.get('street2'),
          city: document.get('city'),
          state: document.get('state'),
          zipCode: int.parse(document.get('zipCode').toString()),
          bedRooms: document.get('bedRooms'),
          bathRooms: document.get('bathRooms'),
          lotSize: document.get('lotSize'),
          schoolDistric: document.get('schoolDistric'),
          taxes: double.parse(document.get('taxes').toString()),
          homeFeatures: document.get('homeFeatures'),
          floorPlans: document.get('floorPlans'),
          propertySurvey: document.get('propertySurvey'),
          yearBuilt: document.get('yearBuilt'),
          listingAgentName: document.get('listingAgentName'),
          listingAgentEmail: document.get('listingAgentEmail'),
          listingAgentPhone: document.get('listingAgentPhone'),
          dayStore:
              DateTime.parse(document.get('dayStore').toDate().toString()),
          downPayment: document.get('downPayment'),
          county: document.get('county'),
          url: document.get('url'),
          listingType: document.get('listingType'),
          isFavorite: favoriteSnapshot.exists,
        ),
      );
    });

    _items = listingList;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Which basically helps me fill the array called _items with the data.

The issue that I'm having is that in order to save the log users favorites I save those in a independent collection.

I those work, but the problem is that on initial load of the Screen that displays those objects it shows empty:

[image: Empty Initial Screen]

However if I click on Likes (Basically Change the Screen) it loads:

[image: Likes Screen]

and Then I go back and it shows all items:

[image: New initial Screen]

I believe it is the evaluation on:

```
DocumentSnapshot favoriteSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .doc('userfavorites/${user.uid}/favorites/${document.id}')
              .get();
```

Which is giving the Issue, although I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any Ideas?

Kind Regards

Comment: Could you try to use StreamBuilder?

Comment: Hi Mardel, can you let me know how to add the StreamBuilder in code, as I'm not sure how to use it. 

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use StreamBuilder like other widgets.

And we can add some functions like `orderBy`, `limit`, `where`.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('listings')
        .orderBy('created', descending: true)
        .limit(20)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            DateTime dateTime =
                DateTime.parse(document['created'].toDate().toString());
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(dateTime);

            reutrn Text(strDate);
          },
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,          
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        // return snapshot.error;
        return Container();
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the problem and the solution:

So the Issue was actually the line:

```
snapshot.docs.forEach((document) async {
```

So the after it was doing the favStat which it does the evalution on another Collection, in this case it was basically sending a Future chained by another Future.

So the chained futures were basically giving the issue, so to avoided I change that line from using the function forEach (which sends a Future), to a regular For loop:

```
for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
```

That way it loops over the content of snapshot.docs and awaits the evalution of the favStat, and doesn't return until the favStat has finished evaluting.

Kind Regards